# Show Multiple Post Thumbnails only in one page

Tags: wordpress

I use Multiple Post Thumbnails plugin to add many thumbnails to my page.

```
for($i=1; $i<=10;$i++){
        new MultiPostThumbnails(
            array(
                'label' => 'Photo - '.$i,
                'id' => 'Photo-'.$i,
                'post_type' => 'page'
            )
        );
    }
```

But I need to have them only in one of the pages, not all. Now if I open any pages in admin, I see 10 Post Thumbnails fields. I need to specify the ID on the page and see them only in that page in admin.

Comment: So you only need this extra thumbnails to be active on one page? I don't get what you are asking...

Comment: I have a pages: home, about us, contact us, gallery. I need to show that Post Thumbnails only in home page. So when I open home page via admin, I could see them in admin page.